# Rails 7 won't generate a destroy path for the comment deletion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, routes, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm trying to make a delete helper for a comment, this is the html code :

```
<% if store_comment.user_id == current_user.id %>
    <%= link_to 'edit', edit_store_post_store_comment_path(params[:name], store_comment.id) %>
    <%= link_to 'delete', delete_store_post_store_comment_path(params[:name], store_comment.id), data: { 'turbo-method': :delete,
                        turbo_confirm: 'You sure?'} %>

<% end %>
```

And this is the routes I have :

```
'delete /store_posts/:store_post_id/store_comments/:id', to : 'store_comment#destroy'

resources :store_posts do
    resources :store_comments,      only: [:create, :edit, :update, :new, :destroy]
end
```

But when I run rails routes in console, I only get those helpers for the comments controller:

```
store_post_store_comments      POST   /store_posts/:store_post_id/store_comments(.:format)                                              store_comments#create
new_store_post_store_comment   GET    /store_posts/:store_post_id/store_comments/new(.:format)                                          store_comments#new
edit_store_post_store_comment  GET    /store_posts/:store_post_id/store_comments/:id/edit(.:format)                                     store_comments#edit
store_post_store_comment       PATCH  /store_posts/:store_post_id/store_comments/:id(.:format)                                          store_comments#update
                               PUT    /store_posts/:store_post_id/store_comments/:id(.:format)                                          store_comments#update
                               DELETE /store_posts/:store_post_id/store_comments/:id(.:format)                                          store_comments#destroy
```

As you can see, the destroy route has no helper, I need it so I can call it to match the action in the comment controller

Comment: `/store_posts/:store_post_id/store_comments/:id` _is_ the path. Requests to that path with an HTTP method of `DELETE` will route to `store_comments#destroy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting confused between paths and route helpers. As you can see, the URL for the delete operation is the same as for update. You can just use that helper in order to create the path/URL and just use the `*method: :delete` option as you already are.

That being said, in Rails 7 (sans rails-ujs) you won't be able to use `link_to`, you'll need to use `button_to` so it creates a little form.